# Keyword based nearest neighbour algorithm or library

Tags: java, algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I want to find a library or an algorithm (so I write the code myself) for identifying the nearest k neighbours of a webpage, where the webpage is defined as being a set of keywords. I have already done the part where I extract the keywords.

It doesn't have to be very good, just good enough.

Can anyone suggest a solution, or where to start. I have looked through lectures by Yury Lifshits in the past, but I am hoping to get something ready-made if possible.

Java libraries preferred.

Comment: are you mapping the locations, or do you want an algorithm that relates the different pages based on their keywords only?

Comment: you could create a weighted undirected graph of website nodes, and have the edge weigths represent the "nearness". e.g. every keyword two sites have in common could be an increase in their edge weigth. there are lots of graph libs in java you could use.

Comment: @smegbrains, yep I think that's what I've done. I've computed the intersection of the pairs of keywords (which I think is equivalent to what you call the 'edge width')

Comment: Your problem sounds like an application of text-mining and document clustering.  Try [this survey paper](http://www.inma.ucl.ac.be/~blondel/publications/08-textmining.pdf) to see if it gives you any hints of papers to look at.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you already have the keywords extracted from a page. I am assuming that you represent each document/page by a vector of words. Something like a [document term-frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix) matrix.

I guess the nearest neighbour of a page is ideally a page with similar contents. So you'd like to find documents where the relative frequency of each word is similar to the one you are searching for. So first normalize the doc-term matrix WRT each row; i.e. replace the occurrence count by %tage occurrence.

Next you have to assign some distance between 2 documents represented by these vectors. You can use the normal [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) or [Manhattan Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). However for text document the similarity measure that usually works best is [Cosine Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). Use whatever distance or similarity function suits your problem (remember for nearest neighbour you want to minimize the distance; but maximize similarity).

Once you have the vectors and your distance function in place, run the [Nearest neighbour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm) or the [K-Nearest neighbour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, you're right each page has a vector (size 6 - for convenience) of keywords. I will simply take the intersection of the set of keywords for each pair and that will give a simple and dirty measure of the similarity.

Comment: In case this is a hobby/homework, that measure will do fine. But if you are doing some ML work, you need to use some more rigorous and time tested methods.